# combo box - drop down list

Tags: c#, winforms

i was wondering if it is possible to create a combo box (drop down list) and to paint specific cells in the drop down list.
so, if i have five items in the drop down list, the second item and the last item will be painted in blue for example and the others in gray..
is it possible?

```
System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox;
comboBox = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
comboBox.AllowDrop = true;
comboBox.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
comboBox.FormattingEnabled = true;
comboBox.Items.AddRange(excel.getPlanNames());
comboBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
comboBox.Name = "comboBox1";
comboBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(sizeX, sizeY);
comboBox.TabIndex = 0;
group.Controls.Add(comboBox);
```

thank's for any help..

Comment: [Microsoft provides an example in the MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DrawItem` Event.

First you have to set the `DrawMode` of the `ComboBox` to `OwnerDrawFixed`

Then you set the `DrawItem` to something like the following:

```
private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    Font font = (sender as ComboBox).Font;
    Brush backgroundColor;
    Brush textColor;

    if (e.Index == 1 || e.Index == 3)
    {
        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {
            backgroundColor = Brushes.Red;
            textColor = Brushes.Black;
        }
        else
        {
            backgroundColor = Brushes.Green;
            textColor = Brushes.Black;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {
            backgroundColor = SystemBrushes.Highlight;
            textColor = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;
        }
        else
        {
            backgroundColor = SystemBrushes.Window;
            textColor = SystemBrushes.WindowText;
        }
    }
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backgroundColor, e.Bounds);
    e.Graphics.DrawString((sender as ComboBox).Items[e.Index].ToString(), font, textColor, e.Bounds);
}
```

This example will make the default background colour Green with black text, and the highlighted item will have a red background and black text, of the items at indexes 1 and 3.

You could also set the font of individual items using the `font` variable.